# For dentro de um Switch Java

Tags: java, switch, case

Boa noite,
Gostaria de saber se há como declarar um 'FOR' dentro de uma CASE de SWITCH em Java pois o Netbeans está acusando um erro bem nesta parte. Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação para realizar um jogo de adivinhação assim como eu li no site

http://www.vivendoentresimbolos.com/2012/07/o-truque-da-adivinhacao-egipcia.html

Vou postar o código todo para avaliação dos mais experientes. Gostaria de opiniões a respeito no funcionamento como um todo caso encontrem alguma falha.

```
package advinhacao;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * By Lucas Menchone
 */
public class Advinhacao {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean fim;
    String resposta;
    int numero,
        i,
        caso,
        resultado;

    resultado = 0;
    numero = 1;
    i = 1;
    fim = false;

    System.out.printf("Jogo da advinhação\n pense em um número entre 10 a 100. \n"
            + "O computador irá perguntar várias vezes se seu numero é par ou impar.\n"
            + "A cada vez que for impar, mentalmente subtraia uma unidade do numero e depois divida-o por 2\n"
            + "A cada vez que for par, divida mentalmente o numero por 2\n"
            + "O jogo termina quando o resultado final das suas contas for 1");

    while (fim == false) {
        int soma[] = new int[i];
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("O numero é impar ? digite 1 se sim, 2 se n ou 3 se o valor final resultou 1");
        resposta = entrada.nextLine();
        caso = Integer.parseInt(resposta);
        switch (caso) {
            case 1:
                numero -= 1;
                numero /= 2;
                soma[i] = numero;
                i++;
                break;

            case 2:
                numero /= 2;
                break;

            case 3:
                for (i !== 0, i-- ) //NESTE 'FOR' ESTA DANDO "';' EXPECTED" e eu não tenho ideia de onde faltou ';' aqui ou se realmente eu estou fazendo algo q n posso
                { 
                    resultado += soma[i];
                }
                fim = true;
                System.out.println(resultado);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("opção não disponível, por favor selecione 1,2 ou 3");

        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Erro semantico isso. cloque o `;` que resolve.

Comment: mas é que eu nunca vi colocar ';' em FOR, pois ele abre e fecha com '{', então nessa situação isso é improvável

Comment: Até onde eu sei, em quase todas as linguagens, o FOR segue essa estrutura. "for (x=y;x<z;x++){." Com ";". Não sei se essa "variação" com "," funciona no java. Mas tenho quase certeza que não.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como eu disse, é um erro semantico no seu for:

```
for(i !== 0, i-- )
```

Não se separa instruções dentro do for com virgula, e sim com `;`:

```
  case 3:
    for (;i != 0; i-- )
     { 
          resultado += soma[i];
     }
```

Dessa forma você está ignorando a declaração do iterator, já que você iniciou ele fora.

Talvez o `while` se encaixaria melhor:

```
while(i != 0){
  resultado += soma[i];
  i--;
}
```

Comment: Realmente, fazendo desta forma não tive erros com relação a sintaxe, obrigado